# How to set different version based on profile maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a java project with mvn
I need to have different version based on the mvn profile

```
<GroupId>com.company.com</GroupId>
<ArtifactId>xxx<ArtifactId/>
<Version>{version.profile}</version>
```

How do I set version.profile based on the profile ?

Comment: What do you mean by ` I need to have different version ` ... for a dependency or for the project itself? Please pom the full pom file?

Comment: This sounds like you are overworking a single pom. Consider splitting into more than one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create profiles like below

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>demo1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <demolib.version>1.0.0</demolib.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>demo2</id>
        <properties>
            <demolib.version>2.0.0</demolib.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

then your default profile is demo1, and version is 1.0.0
you can use variables in profile in your maven

```
<GroupId>com.company.com</GroupId>
<ArtifactId>xxx<ArtifactId/>
<Version>{demolib.version}</version>
```

if you want to build with version 2.0.0
just run maven with
`mvn -Pdemo2 package`
also you can use multiple parameter like
`mvn -Pdemo2,example2 package`